# how to resolve unmet dependencies in ubuntu(16.04)?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

i install  libstdc++.so.6.0.9 then after this my ubuntu give this error

latitude$sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5 is installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
And when I run 
asad@asad-Latitude-E7440:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: Please move this question to AskUbuntu

Comment: I know I have tried to install wrong version of libstdc++6.But what is the way to accurate it.I will also post this question to askUbuntu.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

will sort your message for analyzing, met the same situation

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... failed. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5 is installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

at first, you can run the command

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --remove libstdc++6
```

and then download the latest libstdc++6 and install it
BTW, you can search the latest libstdc++6 from the below link? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64?text=libstdc%2B%2B6

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/385645739/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11_amd64.deb
```

finally, you can run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks any one .My problem has solved.I m giving here for anyone who will have this problem. Solution is
**sudo aptitude purge libstdc++6**

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was trying to install an application on Ubuntu 18.04 where I faced this issue. I went through a lot of troubleshoots and finally, one of the methods helped me.

Once I got the dependency error, I used the command $sudo apt-get install aptitude. Then I installed the application through aptitude command. The syntax is 
$sudo aptitude install app_name.

To my surprise, my required app got installed.

My doubt is that, will this method work for all the unmet dependencies error and for all applications?